# Highchart pie at top of div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, lazy-high-charts

I am using a rails gem (lazy_high_charts) to help pass attributes to a pie chart powered by highcharts. I want the pie chart to start at the top of a div. Currently, there is a lot of space between the top of the div and the beginning of the pie chart. I have used spacingTop=0 and haven't had any success with that.

[image: Img of space I want removed]

The code for this looks like the following:

```
@chart = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('pie') do |f|
  f.chart({:defaultSeriesType=>"pie", :backgroundColor=>"transparent", :margin=>[10, 10, 10, 10], 
                             :spacingTop=>0, :spacingBottom=>0, :spacingLeft=>0, :spacingRight=>0})
  series = {
            :type=> 'pie',
            :name=> '$',
            :data=> [
               ['Lent',   @account.Available_Cash_Balance__c],
               ['Available Funds',   @account.Total_Pledged__c],
               ['Pledged',   100000]
            ]
  }
  f.series(series)
  f.legend(:layout=> 'vertical', :itemMarginTop=>0, :itemMarginBottom=>0)
  f.plot_options(:pie=>{
       :allowPointSelect=>true, 
       :cursor=>"pointer",
       :showInLegend=>true,
       :dataLabels=>{
       :enabled=>false
  }
  })
end
```

Comment: Have you tried to set [center](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.center) parameter?

Comment: @SebastianBochan That doesn't doesn't fix my issue. I'm starting to wonder it might be because I'm using a highcharts gem for rails.

Comment: Sorry Im not familiar with the rails and this gem.